# How to check the modify time of a remote file

Tags: c#

I Am in need of knowing the last modification `DateTime` of a remote file prior to downloading the entire content. This to save up on downloading bytes I am never going to need anyway.

Currently I am using `WebClient` to download the file. It is not needed to keep the use of `WebClient` specifically. The Last-Modified key can be found within the response headers but the entire file is downloaded at that point in time.

```
WebClient           webClient        = new WebClient();
byte[]              buffer           = webClient.DownloadData( uri );
WebHeaderCollection webClientHeaders = webClient.ResponseHeaders;
String              modified         = webClientHeaders.GetKey( "Last-Modified" );
```

Also I am not sure if that key is always included at each file on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HTTP "HEAD" method to just get the file's headers.

```
...
var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "HEAD";
...
```

Then you can extract the last modified date and check whether to download the file or not.

Just be aware that not all servers implement Last-modified properly.

Comment: What is request? Can't find any 'Method' in WebClient.

Comment: Can't find it in System.Net.HttpRequestHeader / HttpRepsonseHeader either.

Comment: You have to set it on the request object, see the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.method(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Comparing `HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength` to the result of `new FileInfo(url).Length` seems like a decent way to do this if you're checking an image and you already have a copy of it downloaded.